# Razor exception compiling template

Tags: c#, templates, razor, postal

I'm trying to use Postal to send out emails from a service (not in an ASP.NET project). I keep getting exceptions with the following message:

```
error CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context
```

I'm following the tutorial from the Postal wiki: https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal/wiki/Postal-in-non-web-scenario

My template looks like:

```
@model Namespace1.AlertEmailViewModel

From: support@example.com
To: @Model.FirstName @Model.LastName <@Model.Email>
Subject: Alert! @Model.ShortDescription
```

(The model class in question does exist.)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the current versions of the mvc/razor libs?

Comment: @Marc Gravell I used NuGet to grab Postal, so I would assume that I am if the RazorEngine NuGet package is up to date.

Comment: worth checking, though. Ultimately, adding a cast at the top may be just as simple: `var typedModel = (ModelType) Model;`

Comment: @Marc Gravel RazorEngine is at 2.1.4039.23635. Is there something newer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Postal in a non-web scenario, under the hood it is using our RazorEngine project. Currently, this means it is utilising the v2.1 release currently pushed on NuGet.

The `@model` syntax isn't supported natively in v2.1, but the upcoming v3 release includes this support, as well as other nice things like layouts, thread-safety etc. (https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue in the past for projects that were created using an earlier version of MVC.

To resolve it, if I remember correctly, add this to your App.config file:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: There's no web.config here; this isn't an ASP.NET project.

Comment: Well, you are using the Razor template engine, which means you are referencing the System.Web.Mvc assembly. Put it in your App.config if you're not in a web project..